# Please tell me in what order i should learn these xml based languages/things

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, xquery, xslt-2.0

guys i am learning xml right now and i am really intrested in learning the below languages Please tell me in what order i should learn these things


XML

XSL

XML Schema

XML DTD

XPath

XQuery

Comment: This is like asking which should I learn first; nouns, verbs or adjectives. All of those technologies are intertwined. The only pre-requisite is XML (which is quite simple) from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is very subjective and it strongly depends on your needs. Many of "X-technologies" are also linked in some points so probably it is not possible to learn them separately. It's presumable you will learn XPath during learning XSLT and XQuery (or vice versa) as well as you will need to learn something about XML during studies of XML Schema ...

Hence I think there is no absolutely correct answer for your question. But in my (subjective!) opinion the order you are asking for should be

1. XML - to have necessary basics about structure and relation; you will need them for all other xml based languages
2. XML Schema - to learn how the structure and some types of relations of xml document are described. Many of xml based languages are also described by xml schema.
3. XPath + XSL(T) - to learn how to manipulate with xml documents in means of adressing parts of them, transforming into another formats etc.
4. XQuery - dtto as 3

I'm pretty sure others will disagree with me but I'd omit XML DTD mostly.

Comment: thanks man will try to follow this :)